# How to remove my card info from my iPod?

Tags: ios, ipod

There is no none selection for payment options and it keeps asking me to verify my card info when I want to update apps or get free apps.

How to remove my card info from my iPod?

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove your card info from your Apple ID. You can do this from your iOS device or from iTunes on a Mac or PC.

This article has step-by-step instructions to get to the page where you can edit your payment information.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201266

If you are trying to remove your card when you are being prompted to update your card info, it may not work. Instead, follow the step-by-step instructions from the Settings app.